# creating png files

Tags: php

I made a function to handle jpg and png files, but i get error when trying to upload a png file.

this is the function:

```
function createImg ($type, $src, $dst, $width, $height, $quality) {

$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
if ($type == "jpg/jpeg") {  
    //imagecreatefromjpeg() returns an image identifier representing the image obtained from the given filename.
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
else if ($type == "png") {
    //imagecreatefrompng() returns an image identifier representing the image obtained from the given filename.
    $source = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}
imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,getWidth($src),getHeight($src));
if ($type == "jpg/jpeg") {
    //imagejpeg() creates a JPEG file from the given image. 
    imagejpeg($newImage,$dst,$quality); 
}
else if ($type == "png") {
    //imagepng() creates a PNG file from the given image. 
    imagepng($newImage,$dst,$quality);      
}
return $dst;
```

}

works as it should with jpg, but with png i get this error msg:

Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: gd-png: fatal libpng error: zlib failed to initialize compressor -- stream error in E:...\php\functions.upload.php on line 48

Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in E:...\php\functions.upload.php on line 48

EDIT :

i just changed removed the imagepng(); and used only imagejpeg and it worked like this, i just want jpg files saved anyways. thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is because `imagejpeg` quality can be up to 100, whereas `imagepng` maximum quality is 9.
try this

```
 else if ($type == "png") {
//imagepng() creates a PNG file from the given image. 
$q=9/100;
$quality*=$q;
imagepng($newImage,$dst,$quality);      
}
```

Comment: Actually, 0-9 is the compression rate, 0 being no compression and 9 maximum compression. Thus, '0' is maximum quality.

Answer (score 4):

What value are you using for the quality setting? imagepng() uses values 0-9, whereas imagejpeg() uses 0-100.

Answer (score 4):

Johnny Craig's answer is correct except one thing, it has inverse relationship. 9 - is the most possible compression, and 0 - no compression, so the most possible quality.

```
if ($type == 'png') {
    $quality = round((100 - $quality) * 0.09);
}
```