# Failing in creating thumbs for all mysql post img attachments

Tags: php, image, resize, thumbnails

I am trying to save a copy of all attached images in my site.

Load time si too big so I thought generating thumbnails to show in listing pages was not a bad idea,

This is how I'm trying:

```
 <?php
    include('basedatos.php');
    class ImgResizer {
        var $originalFile = '$newName';
        function ImgResizer($originalFile = '$newName') {
            $this -> originalFile = $originalFile;
        }
        function resize($newWidth, $targetFile) {

            if (empty($newWidth) || empty($targetFile)) {
                return false;
            }
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($this -> originalFile);
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($this -> originalFile);
            $newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
            $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
            if (exif_imagetype($tmp) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
                imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp, $targetFile, 95);
            }else if(exif_imagetype($tmp) != IMAGETYPE_PNG){
                imagecreatefrompng($tmp, $targetFile, 95);
            }else if(exif_imagetype($tmp) != IMAGETYPE_GIF){
                imagecreatefromgif($tmp, $targetFile, 95);
            }else die('invalid image format');

        }

    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM media where iframe <> 1";
    $mediafiles = mysql_query($query);
    while($details = mysql_fetch_array($mediafiles))
    {   // Copy each file from its temp directory to $ROOT

        $temp = '/home/deia1/public_html/'.$details['url'];
        $path = '/home/deia1/public_html/files/uploads/thumbs/'.str_replace('files/uploads/','',$details['url']);

        echo "$temp<br>";
        if(is_dir('/home/deia1/public_html/files/uploads/thumbs/')){
            echo "$path<br>";

                $work = new ImgResizer($temp);
                $work -> resize(300, $path);

        }
    }
         ?>
```

Notices i have two echo's there,

Thats what they log (for the first item, the rest of the errors look pretty much the same):

> /home/deia1/public_html/files/uploads/Detalle-Magrana.jpg
>
> /home/deia1/public_html/files/uploads/thumbs/Detalle-Magrana.jpg
>
> Warning: Wrong parameter count for imagecreatefrompng() in
>   /home/deia1/public_html/includes/thumbs.php on line 21
>   /home/deia1/public_html/files/uploads/video.png
>   /home/deia1/public_html/files/uploads/thumbs/video.png
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]:
>   gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in
>   /home/deia1/public_html/includes/thumbs.php on line 13
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]:
>   '/home/deia1/public_html/files/uploads/video.png' is not a valid JPEG
>   file in /home/deia1/public_html/includes/thumbs.php on line 13

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

-EDIT-

I need to save a resized copy of the image in /thumbs/ path, I don't want to resize the original image.

-EDIT2-

This is the error I get with current code that @Bass Jobsen  suggested for the PNG files, and they generate white images. for jpg seems to work ferfectly:

```
Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: gd-png: fatal libpng error: zlib failed to initialize compressor -- stream error in /home/deia1/public_html/includes/thumbs.php on line 60

Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in /home/deia1/public_html/includes/thumbs.php on line 60
```

Comment: [`exif_imagetype`](http://us.php.net/exif_imagetype) expects a filename as its argument, you're passing in an image resource instead.

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/es/book.imagick.php? I use it at work in order to achieve similar results and it works very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class rewritten based on your code:

```
    class ImgResizer {
        var $originalFile = '$newName';
        function ImgResizer($originalFile = '$newName') {
            $this -> originalFile = $originalFile;
        }
        function resize($newWidth, $targetFile,$quality=90) {

            if (empty($newWidth) || empty($targetFile)) {
                return false;
            }


            if (($imgtype = exif_imagetype($this -> originalFile)) === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($this -> originalFile);
            }else if(($imgtype = exif_imagetype($this -> originalFile)) === IMAGETYPE_PNG){
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($this -> originalFile);
            }else if(($imgtype = exif_imagetype($this -> originalFile)) != IMAGETYPE_GIF){
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($this -> originalFile);
            }else die('invalid image format');


            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($this -> originalFile);
            $newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
            $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
            imagedestroy($src);


            if ($imgtype === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
                imagejpeg($tmp, $targetFile, $quality);
            }else if($imgtype === IMAGETYPE_PNG){
                //see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7878801/1596547

                imagepng($tmp, $targetFile, (int)$quality*9/100);

            }else if($imgtype === IMAGETYPE_GIF){
                imagegif($tmp, $targetFile);
            }
            imagedestroy($tmp);

        }

    }


$work = new ImgResizer('./testdrive/bootstrap-150x150.png');
$work -> resize(30, './thumb.png');
```

Comment: hi, wouldn't 'imagedestroy($temp)' destroy the original image?

Comment: Hey, i edited my question with the error i get for the PNG files, any idea about it? it generates white images..

Comment: PNG's quality its a 0 to 10 value, so changing the 95 for 0.95 solved it ;)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878754/creating-png-files for  your png error or use `imagepng($tmp, $targetFile, 9);`. `imagepng` write the image to file. `imagedestroy` clears the memory.